# loading data from sever (client/server config) in webapp built using JQM and phonegap?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, json, jquery-mobile

We are creating webapp (hybrid) using JS,css,JQM and phonegap. Developed pretty nice GUI.
Now its a web based app that will require users to create account maintain profile. All data is to be loaded from server. Now we dont know where to go from here. That is :

*creating databases on server (MySQL ?)
*How to connect to server and load data (XML/JSON/AJAX)?

That is what combination of technologies to use to get our app to load and upload data on a server?
Client/server configuration?
Ofcourse am not expecting detailed explanation. Plz just giv us an startup and resources to get us started. we have about a month and a half for development.